# Passing a string array from an ajax function to mvc controller

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an array I build up when a row is selected in my bootstrap data table. I then need to pass this from my view to the controller which is going to fire up a partial view. However when I execute the code I get null reference exception in my controller. The code in the controller is just a placeholder for the actual use but is there to show I intend to be looping the array when it is loaded through. Any ideas as to why it would show NULL even though I can see in debug it has values.

AJAX:

```
function MoveSelected() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: '@Url.Action("MoveSelectedRoute", "Transport")',
        data: { orders: completeArray },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#detail_MoveSelectedOrders').html(data);
            $('#modalMoveSelectedOrders').modal('show');
        }
    })
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult MoveSelectedRoute(string[] orders)
{
    string OrdersToMove = string.Empty;
    foreach (string row in orders)
    {
        string orderNo = orders.ToString().PadLeft(10, '0');
        if (OrdersToMove == string.Empty)
        {
            OrdersToMove = orderNo;
        }
        else
            OrdersToMove = OrdersToMove + "," + orderNo;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not shown what `completeArray` is! But assuming it is an array of strings e.g.  `[ "a", 'b', 'c' ]`, then you need to add the `traditional: true,` ajax option.

Comment: Alternatively you need `data: JSIN.stringify({ orders: completeArray }),` and `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',`

Comment: Unfortunately these haven't worked and it is just an array of strings

Comment: Both options I gave you work!

Comment: Stephen I had misread the options you gave and combined them. The stringify didnt work but `traditional: true,` did. If you make this an answer I will mark it. Thanks

Comment: Just noticed your making a GET (the 2nd option only works with a POST)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `traditional: true` ajax option to post back an array to the collection.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    url: '@Url.Action("MoveSelectedRoute", "Transport")',
    data: { orders: completeArray },
    traditional true,
    success: function (data) {
        ....
    }
})
```

Note the `traditional: true` option only works for simple arrays.

And alternative would be to stringify the data, set the content type to `application/json` and make a POST rather than a GET

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    url: '@Url.Action("MoveSelectedRoute", "Transport")',
    data: JSON.stringify({ orders: completeArray }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    success: function (data) {
        ....
    }
})
```

The final alternative is to generate send the values with collection indexers

```
var data = {
    orders[0] = 'abc',
    orders[1] = 'xyz',
    orders[2] = '...'
}
$.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    url: '@Url.Action("MoveSelectedRoute", "Transport")',
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        ....
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `JSON.stringify({ orders: completeArray })` and your C# code will map your array with its parameter.

Comment: When I add the stringify it still receives a null through on the controller unfortunately

Comment: You can try to replace "string[]" by "List<string>"

Comment: Also add those properties to your ajax call : 
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",

Comment: I have tried these but none of them worked unfortunately